# zip variable empty after first use

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

Python 3.2

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
t2 = (5, 6, 7)
z = zip(t, t2)

for x in z:
    print(x)
```

Result:

```
(1, 5)
(2, 6)
(3, 7)
```

Putting in EXACTLY the same loop immediately after, nothing is printed:

```
for x in z:
    print(x)
```

`z` still exists as `<zip object at 0xa8d48ec>`. I can even reassign the `t`, `t2` to be zipped again, but then it only works once and only once, again.

Is this how its supposed to work? There's no mention in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#zip) about this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

That's how it works in python 3.x.  In python2.x, `zip` returned a list of tuples, but for python3.x, `zip` behaves like `itertools.izip` behaved in python2.x.  To regain the python2.x behavior, just construct a list from `zip`'s output:

```
z = list(zip(t,t2))
```

Note that in python3.x, a lot of the builtin functions now return iterators rather than lists (`map`, `zip`, `filter`)

Comment: bit late to the party, but this just had me stumped. It seems crazy that you cannot go back to the start of an iterator and simply using a zip has a modifiable effect. Not easy to understand as Python leads to believe...

Comment: @NeilWalker -- Perhaps not, but there are a lot of really great benefits to lazy iteration that python's iterators enable (consider any kind of non-seekable streaming data).  You can do a lot of processing with very little system overhead compared to the "everything is a list" perspective of the world.

Answer (score 11):

Because `zip` returns an iterator in Python 3.x. If you want to re-use it, then make it a `list` first:

```
z = list(zip(t, t2))
```

Answer (score 6):

`zip` returns an iterator (in Python 3). You can only iterate over an iterator once. The iterator doesn't vanish when it's out of elements, but iterating over it again gives 0 elements. If you want a list, call `list` on it:

```
z = list(zip(t, t2))
```