# using the zip function returns an empty tuple

Tags: python

So this is my code. I was trying out the zip function and I wanted to print out the tuple but I end up getting nothing.

```
list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = [4,5,6]
new_list = zip(list_one, list_two)
for i, k in new_list:
    print(i, k, end = ' ')
print()
print(tuple(new_list))
```

This is the output.

```
1 4 2 5 3 6 
()
```

why  does it just return `()` and not the tuple with tuples inside? That is what I would expect. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is list_one ??

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777219/zip-variable-empty-after-first-use

Comment: `list_one` was eaten by the Markdown formatting; I have fixed it for OP. For reference: if you use triple-backticks to format code, you can't put the first line of code on the same line as the opening backticks - text there is used to tell the Markdown processor what language the code is in, for syntax highlighting.

Comment: This, Will Solve Your Problem, ```list_one = [1,2,3]
list_two = [4,5,6]
new_list = zip(list_one, list_two)

print(tuple(new_list))```

Comment: `zip()` creates iterator which can be used only once. You have to convert to `list()` to use it many times. `new_list = list(zip(list_one, list_two))`