# Simple symmetric encryption with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I want to encrypt some letters by changing each letter with the character in `echaracters` which has the same index as the letter in `characters`.
So, I tried to use `zip()` to iterate over the two lists.
Firstly I iterated over `userInput` and the within the same loop, I iterated over `key` (which is `zip(characters, echaracters)`)
Then I check if `i` is equal to `a` and if the condition is `True` i add `b` to `cipher`.

```
userInput = input("Enter: ")

characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]

echaracters = ["@", "$", "(", "]", "=", ")", "&", "#", "!", "%", "~", "[", "/", ";", "*", "}", "9", "?", "5", "1", "_", ">", "<<", "+", ",", "-"]

key = zip(characters, echaracters)

cipher = ""

for i in userInput:
    for a, b in key:
        if i == a:
            cipher += b

print(cipher)
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter: ABC
@
```

I cannot figure out why it returns only the first symbol. 
DESIRED OUTPUT

```
Enter: ABC
@$(
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `key` becomes empty after the first loop pass

You can try this:

```
key=list(zip(characters, echaracters))
for i in userInput:
    for a, b in key:        
        if i == a:            
            cipher += b
```

Comment: This. Or you can make key a list `key = list(zip(characters, echaracters))` to prevent this behavior too

Comment: I agree, coincidentally, I already added this in answer)

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because 'key', which is a zip-type, loses its value after the first iteration because zip-type is an iterator. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777219/zip-variable-empty-after-first-use) is a similar question.
Your code is a bit complicated. There is easier way to accomplish your task.

```py
userInput = input("Enter: ")
characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
echaracters = ["@", "$", "(", "]", "=", ")", "&", "#", "!", "%", "~", "[", "/", ";", "*", "}", "9", "?", "5", "1", "_", ">", "<<", "+", ",", "-"]

cipher = ""
for i in userInput:
  cipher += echaracters[characters.index(i)]
print(cipher)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SYBMOLS = {
    "A": "@",
    "B": "$",
    "C": "(",
    "D": "]",
    "E": "=",
    "F": ")",
    "G": "&",
    "H": "#",
    "I": "!",
    "J": "%",
    "K": "~",
    "L": "[",
    "M": "/",
    "N": ";",
    "O": "*",
    "P": "}",
    "Q": "9",
    "R": "?",
    "S": "5",
    "T": "1",
    "U": "_",
    "V": ">",
    "W": "<<",
    "X": "+",
    "Y": ",",
    "Z": "-",
}

userInput = input("Enter: ")

for symbol in userInput:
    print(SYBMOLS[symbol], end="")
```

Also, if you want just lists and not a dictionary, instead of:

```
characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
```

You can use

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

print(ascii_uppercase) # example zip(ascii_uppercase, echaracters)

# ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```